# How can I modify the output of Select-Object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, relative-path

I can get file hashes using this code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Test 1" -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object Hash,Path | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-File -encoding ASCII -filepath "file.md5"
```

Which gives me exactly what I want, except I need relative paths (relative to the path for `Get-ChilItem`, e. g. relative to `E:\Test 1`).

I know I can resolve relative paths with this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path "E:\Test 1\*.*" -Recurse -File | Split-Path -NoQualifier
```

This works fine.

But how do I manipulate `Split-Path -NoQualifier` part to the Path output in the first code snippet? Preferably in a single line of code if possible.

EDIT:

Just wanted to clarify looking to output path RELATIVE to INPUT PATH (i.e. "E:\Test 1").

Bottom line looking to mimic output of Linux output from: `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +` which results in something like this:

```
md5hashmd5hashmd5hashmd5hashmd5h \path\to\file\file.ext
```

Code from user stackprotector seems to work! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify each element after `Select-Object` with `ForEach-Object`. To get paths relative to what you input to `Get-ChildItem`, you have to preserve that somehow, e. g. by using a variable (`$basepath`). This is how you can generate your relative path:

```
ForEach-Object {$_.Path = ($_.Path -replace [regex]::Escape($basepath), '').trimstart('\'); $_}
```

So in total:

```
$basepath = 'E:\Test 1'
Get-ChildItem -Path $basepath -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object Hash,Path | ForEach-Object {$_.Path = ($_.Path -replace [regex]::Escape($basepath), '').trimstart('\'); $_} | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-File -encoding ASCII -filepath "file.md5"
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work great, much appreciated. Just had to replace `-leaf` with `-noQualifier` so I get the full relative path.

Comment: @HTWingNut Maybe you can clarify "relative" in your question. Relative to what?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't clarify. Relative to initial path specified i.e. "E:\Test 1". I guess I jumped the gun. seems that even `-noQualifier` doesn't help much either.

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome. Thanks for the help. This seems to do the trick. Basically I was trying to mimic the Linux: `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +` output. I figured there'd probably be a similar straight forward way to do this with Powershell.